# Fit multiple images into a parent element

Tags: css, image, flexbox, aspect-ratio

I have two images with different aspect ratios, and I want to show them either side-by-side or one above the other, depending on the aspect ratio of the parent, like this:

[image: horizontal layout]
[image: vertical layout]

I had hoped that this would be very simple using `flex`, but the results are not what I expected. What am I doing wrong?

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
  div {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://cdn2.picryl.com/photo/1767/01/01/tall-clock-601889-1024.jpg"/>
  <img src="https://www.goodfreephotos.com/cache/united-states/hawaii/other-hawaii/wide-angle-forest-landscape-of-oahu-in-hawaii_800.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.first-img {
  width: 18.5%;
}
.second-img {
  width: 81%;
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
  div {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
    .first-img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .second-img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1g69up3h/9/